# Distribution of OLS predictions

Tags: regression, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, least-squares

Suppose: $y = X\beta + \varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon \sim (0, \Omega) \Rightarrow y|X  \sim (X \beta, \Omega)$
$\hat{\beta}_{ols} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y = \beta +(X'X)^{-1}X'\varepsilon \sim (\beta, \Sigma)$ with $\Sigma \equiv (X'X)^{-1} (X'\Omega X) (X'X)^{-1}$
Assume $\hat{\Omega}\to^p \Omega$, let
$\hat{\Sigma} \equiv (X'X)^{-1} (X'\hat{\Omega} X) (X'X)^{-1}$.
Under mild conditions on $\varepsilon$, the asymptotic distribution 
$\hat{\beta}_{ols} \sim_a N(\beta, \hat{\Sigma})$.

**Question**: what is the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{y}_{ols}\equiv X\hat{\beta}_{ols}$?
I think: $\hat{y}_{ols}\equiv X\hat{\beta}_{ols} \sim_a N(X\beta, X\hat{\Sigma} X')$

Some authors online say: $\hat{y}  \sim N(X\hat{\beta}, \hat{\Omega})$, just plugging in estimates $\hat{\beta}, \hat{\Omega}$.
**Update**: I think they mean for $x_{new}$ the best prediction for the distribution of
 $y|x_{new}$ is $N(x_{new}\hat{\beta}, \hat{\Omega})$.
But why not $N(x_{new}\hat{\beta}, x_{new}\hat{\Sigma}x_{new}')$?

We agree $E[y|x_{new}] = x_{new}\hat{\beta}$, the difference might be
$V[y|x_{new}]=\hat{\Omega}$ vs
$V[E[y|x_{new}]]=x_{new}\hat{\Sigma}x_{new}'$?

If we assume sperical errors & finite sample normality:
$\varepsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2 I_N) \Rightarrow \Sigma \equiv \sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1}
\Rightarrow 
\hat{y}_{ols} \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2  X (X'X)^{-1} X')$.

**Update 2**: perhaps we are computing the distribution of different things.
Them: $y|X  \sim N(X \beta, \Omega)$, estimate $\hat{\beta}, \hat{\Omega}$, plug-in:  $y|x_{new}  \sim N(x_{new} \hat{\beta}, \hat{\Omega})$.
Me: $\hat{E}[y|x_{new}] = x_{new} \hat{\beta} \sim N(x_{new} \beta, x_{new}\hat{\Sigma}x_{new}')$

Their estimand = the predicted distribution of $y|x_{new}$
My estimand = the distribution of the point prediction (conditional expectation) $\hat{E}[y|x_{new}]$
In general standard errors from $\hat{\Omega}$ are larger than $x_{new}\hat{\Sigma}x_{new}'$.
I was wrong when I wrote: Some authors online say: $\hat{y}  \sim N(X\hat{\beta}, \hat{\Omega})$
I should have wrote: Some authors online say: $\hat{y|X}  \sim N(X\hat{\beta}, \hat{\Omega})$

Consider a random sample $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ w/ $\sigma^2$ known.
$\hat{\mu}_{n} \equiv \bar{x}_{n} \sim N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$
What is your best prediction for new data from same DGP $x_{new}$?
Predicted distribution: $x_{new}\sim N(\hat{\mu}_{n}, \sigma^2)$
Distribution of point prediction: $E[x_{new}] = \hat{\mu}_{n} \sim N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$
Question: how do I compute standard errors around the predicted distribution $x_{new}$ in the space of probability distributions?

Julia code to illustrate:

```
using MLJ, LinearAlgebra; using MLJ: matrix
X, y =  @load_boston; x =[ones(506) matrix(X)]; n,p =size(x);
β̂ = x\y; ŷ = x*β̂; ε̂ = y-ŷ; 
s² = (ε̂'ε̂)/(n-p); Σ̂ = s²*(x'x)^-1;

√s²                 # their se(y|x) = 4.79 
sqrt.(diag(x*Σ̂*x')) # my se(ŷ) =[.61 .49 .51 ...]
```

**Summary**:
Suppose: $y = X\beta + \varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon \sim (0, \Omega) \Rightarrow y|X  \sim (X \beta, \Omega)$
$\hat{\beta}_{ols} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y \sim (\beta, \Sigma)$ with $\Sigma \equiv (X'X)^{-1} (X'\Omega X) (X'X)^{-1}$
Assume $\hat{\Omega}\to^p \Omega$, let
$\hat{\Sigma} \equiv (X'X)^{-1} (X'\hat{\Omega} X) (X'X)^{-1}$.

$\hat{\beta}_{ols} \sim_a N(\beta, \hat{\Sigma})$.
$\hat{E}[y|x]=\hat{y}_{ols}\equiv X\hat{\beta}_{ols} \sim_a N(X\beta, X\hat{\Sigma} X')$ (sample mean dist around truth)
$\hat{y|x} \sim_a (X\hat{\beta}_{ols}, \hat{\Omega})$
Note, from CLT we know the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{E}[y|x]$, but not $\hat{y|x}$.
If we make stronger assumptions, eg the finite sample distribution $\varepsilon \sim N(0, \Omega)$, then we can conclude $\hat{y|x} \sim N(X\hat{\beta}_{ols}, \hat{\Omega})$.

Comment: Perhaps this means that $\Omega=X\Sigma X’$. I confess that I’ve forgotten this fact (if it’s even true), but can you prove it?

Comment: Can you link to one of the authors online who think the variance is $\Omega$. I agree with you that they're wrong, but if you want to understand why, we'd need to see more.

Comment: @ThomasLumley I prefer not to post direct links here. Btw, do you agree w/ my logic on the distribution of $\hat{y}$?

Comment: Yes. I do.  But I expect the people who think the variance is $\Omega$ are trying to do something else, rather than just getting this calculation wrong.

Comment: @ThomasLumley Discussion here: https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/MLJ.jl/issues/552#issuecomment-635717073

Comment: I think that the variance of the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\beta}$ is $\Sigma$ and not $\hat{\Sigma}$.